# slid-in view block my button responsiveness at the bottom of the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a main view, and inside this view I have a button that animating another view to come from the bottom if the view to the middle (+-).

at the bottom of the view (slidingView) i have a cancel button, and this button is not responding after animating this view (slidingView)

it works like this:

```
self.slidingView.hidden = NO;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
self.slidingView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,284);
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

if I dont animate, only do  `self.slidingView.hidden = NO;` the button works perfectly.

why is that :// ?

obviously the problem is in here:

```
self.slidingView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,284);
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);
```

my sliding view:

x: 0  y: 284  w: 320  h: 284

my UIImageView (covering the sliding view):

x: 0  y: 0  w: 320  h: 284

my date picker:

x: 0  y: 53  w: 320  h: 162

my button is:

x: 15  y: 233  w: 136  h: 43

this is my interfacebuilder for that controller:

[image]

the sliding view has a uiimageview covering it as you can see, and two ui objects on that uiimageview which is the date picker and the button

but what is wrong..? i didnt implement autolayout yet so it works only on 4 inch
thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us where are the buttons? (frame) It'is possible than they are outside of the slidingView and in that case they can't respond.

Comment: @peig just added x: 15  y: 233  w: 136  h: 43 to the question

Comment: one sec i will upload more important sizes and locations

Comment: Add self.slidingView subviews and self.view.subviews

Comment: try with *bringSubviewToFront* , This method moves the specified view to the end of the array of views in the subviews property.

Comment: @peig please see my edit with all the sizes

Comment: @pawan iv tried it before and it dosent work :/

Comment: @pawan see my edit with the sizes

Comment: You should add you button on view after adding imageview, that way button will be at end of the subviews.

Comment: @pawan i do it all in interface builder..

Comment: Post screenshot of your I/B.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71074/discussion-between-pawan-and-nick-shmick).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the animation placing your view where you want without touching self.view.